# Gem::Install Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to cleanup my rails versions with `sudo gem cleanup rails`

I get the following error:

```
Cleaning up installed gems...
Attempting to uninstall rails-2.3.5
Unable to uninstall rails-2.3.5:
Gem::InstallError: cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rails`
Attempting to uninstall rails-1.2.6
Unable to uninstall rails-1.2.6:
Gem::InstallError: cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rails`
```

`gem list -d rails` results in:

```
rails (2.3.8, 2.3.5, 1.2.6)
  Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
  Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rails
  Homepage: http://www.rubyonrails.org
  Installed at (2.3.8): /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
               (2.3.5): /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
               (1.2.6): /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

  Web-application framework with template engine, control-flow layer,
  and ORM.
```

Any one know what's wrong?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000731/getting-rid-of-ruby-gems-that-wont-die

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some long searches it turns out the reason is because of a non-existent path.  The cannot uninstall comes up because the system doesn't search /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

On a granular level, instead of `gem cleanup rails`, you can simply use the uninstall command and type:

`gem uninstall rails -i /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8`

Then you might hit another problem related to a non-existent path, at which point, you should create a directory using the command:

`mkdir /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin`

Now all uninstalls should work well.  I recommend doing a clean gem reinstall by performing the following functions:

## create a list of all existing gems

`gem list --no-versions | sed -e '/^(*|$)/d' > installed_gems`

## uninstall all existing gems

`gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx`

## reinstalling latest gems

`cat installed_gems | xargs sudo gem install`

Comment: Very helpful. To run the uninstall script though I had to alternate between adding -i /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 and not until all gems were successfully removed.

Comment: I used: gem list --no-versions | xargs sudo gem uninstall -aIx -i /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 **or** gem list --no-versions | xargs sudo gem uninstall -aIx -i /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 depending on where the Gem was installed.

Comment: I just spent the last hour looking through different alternatives and this is the one that worked for me. btw, I DID NOT USE SUDO. God bless you, I'd give you 50 votes if I could

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://gabrito.com/post/mac-os-x-gem-cleanup-failing, proposing:

```
sudo sh -c 'GEM_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 gem cleanup'
```