# gem cleanup shows error: Unable to uninstall bundler-1.0.21 when upgrade to bundler-1.0.22

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

gem cleanup report error:

```
Attempting to uninstall bundler-1.0.21
Unable to uninstall bundler-1.0.21:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "bundler" is not installed
```

But I already cleanuped bundler 1.0.21 and upgrade to bundler 1.0.22.

I use rvm 1.10.2, ruby 1.9.3-p0, under Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Update:

I resolve this problem with the answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060347/623260)

rvm gemset use global

gem uninstall xxx

Comment: Why don't you place your fix into an answer?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly normal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 2):

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler
```

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me as well and solved it using:

`rvm gem set use global`

then

`gem install bundler`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like cleanup command is unable to find out the path, did you try to uninstall using `gem uninstall` command?

Following [link](http://gabrito.com/post/mac-os-x-gem-cleanup-failing) might help you.

Comment: I resolve this problem with following link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4060347/623260 "rvm gemset use global
 gem uninstall xxx"