# Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:

Tags: ruby, rubygems, guard

When launching Guard, I'm getting this output:

```
$ guard
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Contents of Guardfile:

```
guard 'livereload' do
    watch(%r{.+\.(css|js|html)$})
end
guard 'sass', :input => 'css', :style => :compressed, :extension => '.min.css'
```

Comment: I'm getting this too and not even running guard.

Comment: [This post](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1267#issuecomment-281694950) is very helpful if you're using RVM.

Comment: My two cents: Ran across a similar error when running RSpec; Had the gems on my machine, but was told to run `gem cleanup <gem>`; instead, I ran `bundle exec rspec <file>` and it worked

Answer (score 292, accepted):

I was seeing this issue by just running **RSpec** on its own. From what I understand, this means that you have more than one version of the listed gems installed on your system, and RSpec is unsure which one to use. After uninstalling older version of the gems, the warnings went away.

You can try:

```
gem cleanup lumberjack
```

Or:

```
gem list lumberjack

gem uninstall lumberjack
```

If you're using Bundler, you can try `bundle exec guard` (or in my case `bundle exec rspec`).

Comment: You put me on the right track. I was getting errors when running 'gem cleanup' so I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007074/uninstalling-rails-and-gems-getting-error-cannot-uninstall-check-gem-list-d/4060347#4060347


Turns out it had to do with RVM. When I ran 'rvm gemset use global' and ran guard, the errors went away.

Comment: I was using rbenv and gem cleanup [gemname] worked for me perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue, running bundle update solved it

Comment: After `rvm gemset use global` (and `gem cleanup <gemname>`) make sure to switch back to your default gemset with `rvm gemset use default`

Comment: I needed to use `gem uninstall <problematic gem>` but thanks and upvote for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 185):

Using the following command solved it for me:

```
bundle clean --force
```

See [guard-and-unresolved-specs](http://blog.mikecordell.com/2014/01/26/guard-and-unresolved-specs.html) for more info

Comment: I've tried a ton of things, including reinstalling RVM and Ruby, until I bumped into this solution and this did it for me.

Comment: Man, i wasted few hours trying to figure out why Textmate 2 was glitching out when I was running tests. This cleared it out.

Comment: I needed to `su`/`sudo` to do this, since it was trying to write to `/var/lib/gems`. Other than that - works for jekyll.

Comment: I found this while debugging an Issue with the RubyMine debugger: `Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset` for the reline gem. After the force cleanup RubyMine reinstalled the debugger gems, this time seemingly without issues.

Answer (score 27):

Use Bundler. Call `bundle exec guard`, not `guard`.

Answer (score 14):

FYI:

```
gem cleanup
```

worked for me.

```
$ gem cleanup       

Cleaning up installed gems...
Attempting to uninstall builder-3.2.2
Successfully uninstalled builder-3.2.2
Attempting to uninstall amatch-0.3.0
Successfully uninstalled amatch-0.3.0
Attempting to uninstall tins-1.12.0
Successfully uninstalled tins-1.12.0
Clean Up Complete
```

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
bundle clean --force
```

then

```
bundle install
```

to reinstall gems.

Answer (score 6):

I use `gem list gem-name; gem uninstall gem-name` to clean the gem one by one because of the dependency. After that, the error does not show again.

Answer (score 4):

add

```
'bundle exec'
```

before your command.

I use ruby 2.4 and got the same problem when deploying jekyll on windows, it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has come this far and still hasn't found the answer I leave you with this. `gem update --system`. I tried all of these other answers to no avail. Hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, if you want to use guard, you have to add gem guard to Gemfile.

```
group :developement, :test do
  gem 'guard'
end
```

Then, run

```
bundle install
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this message while running Rspec within a Guard plugin gem, using `bundle exec rspec`. It turned out to be a missing line in the `gemspec` file:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
```

This line is normally at the top of the file (in many of the gems I have recently been working in) and I had commented it out to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem uninstall <gem>`
and it will remove all younger versions of gem.

You will then be asked

> "If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met. Continue
> deleting? [YN]"

Select the answer

> "no"

to leave the latest version of gem and all dependencies remain valid.