# rake db:reset throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, napa

I'm following the [napa api framework tutorial](https://github.com/bellycard/napa/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) on how to create APIs. But on running `rake db:reset` its raising the following error

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  minitest (~> 4.2)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Virtus::Configuration::Coercible
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/virtus-1.0.5/lib/virtus/configuration.rb:40:in `initialize'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/virtus-1.0.5/lib/virtus/builder.rb:28:in `new'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/virtus-1.0.5/lib/virtus/builder.rb:28:in `call'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/virtus-1.0.5/lib/virtus.rb:152:in `model'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/representable-1.8.5/lib/representable/coercion.rb:5:in `<class:Coercer>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/representable-1.8.5/lib/representable/coercion.rb:4:in `<module:Coercion>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/representable-1.8.5/lib/representable/coercion.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/roar-0.12.9/lib/roar/representer/feature/coercion.rb:2:in `require'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/roar-0.12.9/lib/roar/representer/feature/coercion.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/napa-0.4.3/lib/napa/output_formatters/representer.rb:3:in `require'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/napa-0.4.3/lib/napa/output_formatters/representer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/napa-0.4.3/lib/napa.rb:27:in `require'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/napa-0.4.3/lib/napa.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jay/AppService/app.rb:6:in `require'
/home/jay/AppService/app.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
/home/jay/AppService/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p576/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is already similar question on SO. Maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936340/unresolved-specs-during-gemspecification-reset

Comment: it doesn't help ....

Answer (score 0):

A year later I am running into a similar issue.  I've resolved it.  While trying to run through Napa quickstart on Mac OS El Capitan I noticed that it was pulling napa 0.5.1 which was not compatible.  First thing I did was change to napa 0.5.0.

The next thing was to change active-record 4.2.0 from 4.0.0 which got rid of the minitest gem issue.

I hope this helps anyone visiting napa for the first time and can't get the quicstart to work.

Also, I tried the quickstart with MySQl and not Postgres which the tutorial uses.