# Ruby Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset with installed gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I have a gem which we'll call  `mygem` that has an executable used as a CLI tool.

The file `mygem/bin/mygem`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'bundler/setup'
....code goes here....
```

`mygem.gemspec`:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  gem.bindir      = 'bin'
  gem.executables = ['mygem']
end
```

Build and install:

```
gem build mygem.gemspec
gem install mygem-0.1.0.gem
<optionally bundle install, but that won't fix the error>
```

And, at the end, I can successfully call `mygem` from the command line and the script runs.

The issue is that it can only run from a folder that does *not* contain a `Gemfile`. When doing otherwise, the system outputs an error:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      json (>= 0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Could not find differ-0.1.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

The actual gems that show up in this error message vary depending on the Gemfile in the current directory.

Running `bundle exec mygem` suppresses part of the error message, but still fails to execute unless `bundle install` is run on the *other* application's Gemfile:

```
Could not find differ-0.1.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The error looks pretty typical. It's saying it can't find the gem in your gemfile, which loads your dependencies. Usually bundle install adds them all with no probelms, but I've had issues like this before and had to manually put entries into the gemfile.

In the case you're making an example for, try adding to the gemfile:

```
gem 'differ'
```

Comment: @Drew Have you checked out other posts on similar/the same error messages? Did a quick google search and found a lot of questions/answers. This might be up your alley: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936340/unresolved-specs-during-gemspecification-reset