# Trouble Installing Jekyll on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, jekyll, windows-7-x64, github-pages

I am trying to install Jekyll on my windows 7 desktop and I keep getting this error in cmd. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks!

```
C:\Users\Mac\Documents\Github\mackiser.github.io>jekyll build
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  rouge (~> 1.7)
  ffi (>= 0.5.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-         1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:
95:in `block in materialize': Could not find listen-3.0.6 in any of the sources
(Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/environment.rb:19:in `requested_specs'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler
.rb:95:in `setup'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/pl
ugin_manager.rb:36:in `require_from_bundler'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:9:
in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from C:/tools/ruby23/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936340/unresolved-specs-during-gemspecification-reset)

Answer (score 0):

From Jekyll 3, the suggested way to run Jekyll is through the Bundler (http://bundler.io/). This solves a lot of Gem-related headaches and versioning issues. Rather than running with `jekyll build`, try the following commands from http://jekyllrb.com/:

Install your dependencies (only necessary initially or after you add a plugin):

```
bundle install
```

Run jekyll with those dependencies:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but it'd be a good start.