# RSpec tests failing - Display socket is taken but lock file is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, lockfile

I'm trying to run RSpec tests in my Rails application and keep getting the following error:

```
:> rspec spec/controllers/api/v0/buying_strategies_controller_spec.rb
    WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      activemodel (< 6.0, >= 3.0, >= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, >= 4.2.0)
   WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
   Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/Users/christopherdanella/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/headless-2.3.1/lib/headless.rb:207:in `ensure_xvfb_launched': Display socket is taken but lock file is missing - check the Headless troubleshooting guide (Headless::Exception)
from /Users/christopherdanella/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/headless-2.3.1/lib/headless.rb:195:in `launch_xvfb'
```

The Troubleshooting guide here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/leonid-shevtsov/headless#Display_socket_is_taken_but_lock_file_is_missing just says it's an exceptional situation and to open an issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean up the gems, it seems to be that you have many versions of the same gems and the rspec doesn't know which one to use.

Look at this answer from another QA:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127613/7219974