# What are these errors from a gem trying to tell me?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am running a program from the 'coursegen' gem which I am writing and I'm getting these errors which I don't understand.

```
Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1288:in `reset': WARN: Unresolved or ambigious specs during Gem::Specification.reset: (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1290:in `block in reset':       rack (>= 1.0.0, < 3.0.0) (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1294:in `block in reset':       Available/installed versions of this gem: (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 2.2.3 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 2.2.2 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1290:in `block in reset':       thor (>= 0.18.1) (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1294:in `block in reset':       Available/installed versions of this gem: (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 1.0.1 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 0.20.3 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1290:in `block in reset':       lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0) (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1294:in `block in reset':       Available/installed versions of this gem: (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 1.2.6 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 1.2.5 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1290:in `block in reset':       kramdown (>= 0) (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1294:in `block in reset':       Available/installed versions of this gem: (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 2.3.0 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 2.2.1 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1290:in `block in reset':       minitest (~> 5.1) (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1294:in `block in reset':       Available/installed versions of this gem: (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 5.14.1 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block (2 levels) in reset':       - 5.14.0 (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1298:in `reset': WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Try 'gem cleanup <gem>' (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1299:in `reset': Please report a bug if this causes problems. (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
    done
```

Comment: Which exact command causes this error? `cg serve`, `cg view` etc?

Comment: It looks like this question could be useful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936340/unresolved-specs-during-gemspecification-reset, because you also have some gems with multiple versions installed (`rack`, `thor`, `lumberjack`, `kramdown` and `minitest` according to your log).

Comment: Did you try `gem cleanup`?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Gemfile.lock file and run `bundle install`?

Comment: I think that fixed it.