# Uninstalling Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, uninstallation

```
user@machine:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
minitest (5.8.4)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.7)
psych (2.0.17)
rake (10.5.0)
rdoc (4.2.1)
sass (3.4.23)
test-unit (3.1.7)
user@machine:~$ sudo gem uninstall rake
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    rake is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all rake
user@machine:~$ sudo gem uninstall -i /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all rake 
Remove executables:
    rake

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  Y
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/bin directory.
user@machine:~$ ls /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/
specifications
user@machine:~$
```

I can not uninstall this gem in particular, neither use it :(
If seems that it doesn't exist.

My ruby verison is 2.3.1.p112

Answer (score 7):

Ideally you would use RVM or rbenv to create a local sandbox and handle your Ruby install and gems instead of the system default. Then you won't have to use `sudo` you can just use `gem uninstall <gem>`. It doesn't let you have access for a reason, so it's harder to accidentally mess up the system Ruby.

If you can just read these [install directions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to get set up with RVM and then install the gems you used previously in your new environment. It'll save you a lot headaches in the future managing Ruby and gems.

--

If you don't want to do that you could try this answer

Try this answer from this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007074/uninstalling-rails-and-gems-getting-error-cannot-uninstall-check-gem-list-d).

`gem list -d 'name of gem'` and note the "Installed at:" location

`sudo gem uninstall 'name of gem' -i 'the path noted above'`

If it still returns a permissions error. Create a folder /bin, in the path above. Continue uninstalling as in step 2, still using the original path (/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is not a magic wand that casts a spell “do it anyway.”

When you list your gems, you execute plain `gem list` from **the user**. It lists gems installed for **the user**. Afterwards you try `sudo gem uninstall rake`. Why do you expect superuser’s list of gems being the same as user’s one?

To remove user’s gems, listed with `gem list`, use `gem uninstall rake`. Without `sudo`.

To list superuser’s gems, that you were tried to remove with `sudo gem uninstall rake`, use `sudo gem list`. With `sudo`.

More info on `sudo`: http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html

Comment: I was uninstalled but for some reason there were some files remaining. I removed manually and everything is fine now. I tried to install rake and uninstall it and now works fine.